# How to import or use functions defined in third party namespace in javascript?

Tags: javascript, javascript-namespaces

This could be the very basic question of javascript but i am not able to figure out to use the namespance named `AudioBridge` from the kandy.js file but i dont how should i import the `audioBridge` namesame in my own js and use it.

Here is the [CDN link of kandy.js](https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@kandy-io/link-sdk@v3.4.1)

Following is the screenshot of the kandy apis `AudioBridge` feature , how shall i able to use these apis defined in the `kandy.js`

[image]

[Link to kandy documentation](https://docs.kandy.io/references/link#audiobridge)

Comment: Tells you right here: https://docs.kandy.io/references/link#create. Remember to mark your script as a module. `<script src="mySrcUrl" type="module"><script>` this will allow import to work correctly.

Comment: Some more info on using import here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/import

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your html you will have you script tag like this:

```html
    <script src="myJavascriptFile.js" type="module"></script>
```

The `type` is required and will allow you to use imports in your `script`.

Your Javascript file will then look like this:

```
    import { create } from '/whereEverIStore/kandy.js';

    const client = create({
      authentication: { ... },
      logs: { ... },
      // .... more
    });
```

I hope this helps.

NOTE: the `{ create }` syntax is destructuring and can be found here: [MDN Destructuring](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment)

Comment: i can use create , but how shall i use `AudioBridge`

Comment: shall i use this way `<script src="Kandy.js" type="audioBridge"></script>` ?

Comment: I suspect you need `import { create, AudioBridge }`

Comment: No, you do not need a `script` tag for Kandy when using import.

Comment: okay so as `AudioBridge` has static members after using `import { create, AudioBridge } `   can i invoke its method like `AudioBridge.create();`

Comment: I think this answers it for you, take a look here: https://codepen.io/pen/?editors=1010, notice how the use `create` to get a `kandy` object. This will then give you access to AudioBridge

Comment: @Bibberty That link leads to a new codepen, not yours.

Comment: Correct, the codepen is example code from their site. Notice how they create their `kandy` object, I would start there.

Comment: apologies, look here and go to the bottom for the CP link: https://docs.kandy.io/quickstarts/javascript/link/Voice%20and%20Video%20Calls

Comment: @Bibberty yes i can see the codepen and able to run it , but if i use `import { create, AudioBridge }` and console the `AudioBridge` it shows `undefined`. Probably it is not getting imported

Comment: No, ignore my earlier blabbering and follow the codepen. I assume AudioBridge is part of the Kandy object.

Comment: think `kandy.audioBridge.create()`, or in the code above `client.audioBridge.create()`

Comment: Happy coding !!, glad your up and running.